# An example of a function not invariant under complex conjugation

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. The complex conjugation induces naturally  an anti-holomorphic function $\sigma: X\to X$. A $C^{\infty}$-function $f:U\to \mathbb C $ is said invariant under conjugation if $f=f\circ\sigma$.

> what is an example of function $f$ which is not invariant under conjugation?

This is a rather basic question, but I have a conceptual problem: $\sigma$ as function between sets is just the identity, we just change the charts by composing with the conjugation. So I don't understand how the equality $f=f\circ\sigma$ can fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex conjugation" on an abstract complex manifold? There are complex manifolds that do not admit any antiholomorphic automorphisms (see [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3052321/1421), for example).

Comment: I mean chaneging the charts with the conjugate ones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious example: Let $X=\mathbb{C}$, then $\sigma$ is just the usual complex conjugation.  The identity function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is not invariant under conjugation, because $\operatorname{id}\circ\sigma=\sigma\neq\operatorname{id}$.  Similarly the "imaginary part" is not invariant (it gains a minus sign).

On the other hand, the "real part" is invariant under $\sigma$.

Comment: Ok this is rather obvious. I had some troubles with the issue about charts.

Comment: OK, an example with some charts.  Take $X=\mathbb{CP}^n$ with the usual charts $Z\mapsto (Z_0/Z_i,\dots,\hat{i},\dots,Z_n/Z_i)$.  We can write down an explicit isomorphism $\sigma\colon\mathbb{CP}^n\to\mathbb{CP}^n$ that corresponds to conjugation in the charts, namely $Z\mapsto \bar{Z}$.  The smooth function $Z\mapsto Z_j/\lVert Z\rVert$ is not invariant under conjugation, because the conjugate is $Z\mapsto\bar Z_j/\lVert Z\rVert$.